# 10x10 Two dimensional array and search minimum, maximum value and its index location

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

```
int[][] numList = new int[10][10];
        int column;
        for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
            for (column = 0; column < 10; column++) {
                numList[row][column] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
                System.out.print(numList[row][column] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please specify your question.

Comment: i want to know the highest and smallest value base on the 10x10 matrix.

Comment: Please edit your question: what you are trying to do, what the code snippet is supposed to be, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Test1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numList[][]=new int[10][10]; 
    int max=0;
    int min=999;
    int minX=0;
    int maxX=0;
    int minY=0;
    int maxY=0;
    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < 10; column++) {
                int num=(int)(Math.random()*100);
                numList[row][column] = num;
                if(num>max){
                    max=num;
                    maxX=row;
                    maxY=column;
                }
                if(num<min){
                    min=num;
                    minX=row;
                    minY=column;
                }
                System.out.print(numList[row][column] + "\t");
         }
                System.out.println("");
    }
    System.out.println("Max value=>"+max+"["+maxX+","+maxY+"]");
    System.out.println("Min value=>"+min+"["+minX+","+minY+"]");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your code is only inserting data into 2 dimensional array. To find min and max inside array and its corresponding index you need to write a function `search` as shown follow:

```
public class prog{

    public void search(  int[][] numList )
 {
     int max=0;
     int maxX=0;
     int maxY=0;
     int min=0;
     int minX=0;
     int minY=0;
     for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < 10; column++) {
                if( min >  numList[row][column])
                {
                     min = numList[row][column];
                     minX=row;
                     minY= column;
                }
                if( max <  numList[row][column])
                {
                    max= numList[row][column];
                    maxX=row;
                    maxY=column;
                }
            }
     }
      System.out.print("MinX:"+ minX+ " MinY: "+ minY+ " MaxX:"+ maxX+ " MaxY:"+ maxY);
 }
public static void main(String[] args){

        int[][] numList = new int[10][10];
        int column;
        for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
            for (column = 0; column < 10; column++) {
                numList[row][column] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
                System.out.print(numList[row][column] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        prog obj = new prog();
        obj.search( numList);

}
```